# Scalable and dynamic graph visualization library in C++

Tags: c++, graph, visualization

I am developing a piece of software that makes an intensive use of graphs. I'd like to visualize these graphs (they may become quite large). Is there a good C++ library (or in another language, but with a C++ API) that allows for fast, easy, and scalable visualization of graphs?

I would be interested in features such as zooming on some parts of the graph, or have 3-d rendering using OpenGL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you use Boost.Graph? Then you can write .dot-files with [write_graphviz](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/graph/doc/write-graphviz.html) and let GraphViz do the drawing.

Comment: Even if you don't use BGL the graphviz input format is trivial to create.  But the only help you'll get with zooming is if you create a PDF or SVG and zoom in on that.

Answer (score 0):

Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492893/graph-drawing-c-library

Comment: yes indeed :P actually, I'm looking for a very scalable library that would allow things like zooming or 3d rendering